# ansible task using replace module runs ok but strings are not replaced

Tags: ansible

I am using a combination of the ansible find and replace modules to change string in some xml files. The task runs ok but the strings are not replaced.

Here is what the task looks like:

```yaml
- name: Find common module config files
  find:
    paths: "/etc/app/common/"
    patterns: "*.xml"
  register: commonConfigs

- name: Set compress to false in common modules
  become: yes
  replace:
    path: "{{item.path}}"
    regexp: "<compress>true"
    replace: "<compress>false"
  with_items: "{{ commonConfigs.files }}"
```

I thought that the `regexp` might be the problem so I tried `/<compress>true/g` but that didn't help either.
I am pretty new to ansible so apologies if I confuse some terminologies here.
Thanks for any help

**Edit:**

Here is what part of the xml looks like

```xml
<appConfig>
  <ui>
    <compress>true</compress>
  </ui>
<appConfig>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whithout an example of your xml file, my guess is that your currently searched string does not actually start at the beginning of the line because of indentation.

Moreover, you should catpure the end of the line as well and write it back to make sure you don't loose anything:

```yaml
regexp: "(\s+<compress>)true(.*)"
replace: "\1false\2"
```

Meanwhile, I would not rely on `replace` to make such changes in an xml file when there is an [`xml` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/xml_module.html) you can use precisely for that.